# jQuery append fail in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, object, append

I have this object that I would like to append to my div#doctors-list.

Firefox,Chrome work like a charm.But all IE fail. No errors are shown in the console.

```
$.each(sorteddoctorsArray[i2], function(idx, val) {                 

     if ( !$.browser.msie ) {                                               
          $('div#doctors-list').append(val);
     }else{
          console.log(val);
          // this logs [object Object]
           $('div#doctors-list').append(val); // fails
     }  
});
```

any suggestions?

open it in IE and firefox to see the difference

Comment: If it fails in all versions of IE, that means you can use the developer tools built into IE8 and IE9 to walk through the code and see what's going wrong. Do you see any errors? What happens to the DOM when the append call is run? Fundamentally, `append` works just fine in all versions of IE, which means there's nothing for it but good old-fashioned debugging, which we can't do for you, not from what you've posted.

Comment: no errors in the console. jQuery append and ie problems tend not to have errors. It only doesn't append.

Comment: @musdy: Again: Nothing for it but walking through the code with the dev tools.

Comment: @musdy: Links to live code can be a good *adjunct* to a question, but you really need to quote all of the relevant code *in the question itself*. Above you've just quoted code that will work just fine on IE; there's something *else* going on, elsewhere in the markup and/or code -- not least because the purpose of Stack Overflow isn't just to help you now, but to help others with the same or similar problem in the future, and the content of external sites tends to change / move / go away. (You've *already* changed the code you've linked to, for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('div#doctors-list').html($('div#doctors-list').html()+val);
```

Comment: that printed out [object Object] all over.

Comment: Even if `val` were a string (which we know it isn't, from his question), that would still be a *really really* bad way to append things, not least because it does a huge amount of unnecessary work and wipes out any event handlers hooked up to anything within the relevant `div`. And again, we know `val` *isn't* a string, and so this would just append "[object Object]" to the text.

Comment: this is becuase the val is object too, then this should do: $('div#doctors-list').html($('div#doctors-list').html()+val.html());

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  what is a better way of doing it though? Thinking that val is an object.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani that didn't do anything. Still not appending.

Comment: what is val? is it a div? input?

Comment: @musdy: It depends. What is `val`? (And what were the odds we'd kind of need to know that?)

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani  it is a div. Hey Ashkan, you can seethe code at [link](http://neareasthospital.com/find-a-doctor/)

Comment: well i'm trying to understand the code to see if i can find out what the problem is

Comment: @T.J.Crowder val is a div. If you go to this [link](http://neareasthospital.com/find-a-doctor/) . I log it in the console. That might help better. Try opening in IE and Firefox.

Comment: i see that you have used appendTo, and even tried to append val.html() , the question is, is val a valid object? it seems that val is just an empty object.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani  you can see the object in firefox console. that will help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say when you disable the IE-Code(it currently is commented out).

But one issue I see so far(a few lines above the code posted by you) :

```
$('div#doctors-list').html('');
            for(var i in priority){

                for(var i2 in sorteddoctorsArray){
```

Both, **priority** and **sorteddoctorsArray** are native Arrays, you should never walk native Arrays by using `for...in`, always use `for(var i=0;i<array.length;++i)`

The `for...in` -Syntax will walk trough all members of an object. Also the build-in Array-members, e.g. **length** , will be fetched, what may result in errors.